# How to read Google Analytics browser traffic + AngularJS-WP-WPAPI

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, api, google-analytics, seo

I am trying to determine from the attached Google Analytics stats which spans over the last year, whether my company's website is getting alot of use on browsers like IE8. 
I am unsure how to read/analyse this data as to whether e.g IE8 11.20% is a high number?

Reason being I would like to use some new technology to build a new site for my company possibly using an AngularJS Wordpress Theme w/ WP API, multi-site network where I can reuse some of the post data through API.

Some of the outcomes I am looking for are:
 - Performance
 - Reuse-ability
 - Modular (for maintainability)
 - Partials to manage content/routes

I have built a skeleton AnJS, WP, WPAPI theme through doing tutorials and tried a bunch of shims/workarounds for a couple of days for IE8 but no luck.

Other factors like "compatibility mode" of users browser - not sure how this plays a part? e.g (X-UA-Compatible content=IE=edge) for default rendering.

Target audience there is some oldschool older customers using site who may be a bit computer illiterate..so not sure if I try cater for them too or forcing them to upgrade their browser...

I want to see if I have a valid case and how it would be beneficial, so I don't have to screw around with IE8 hacks.
I am considering other options as your standalone WP theme or WP w/jQuery/ajax calls - this could be a better option if the stats aren't justified.

Thanks your feedback is much appreciated!

[image: G.A stats]

Comment: I think this is more a business question rather than a coding question.  By the looks of things approx 5% of all your sessions use IE8 which appears incredibly high (but is very much market dependent of course).  Probably more interestingly approx 7% of all your users (new users) use IE8.  If you wanted a more in depth analysis of this and guidance we could provide some assistance but only if we can understand your business in greater depth, please contact me through my profile.  We have a large amount of experience dealing with analytics in emerging markets so understand this issue entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thank you for your responses. I have decided to develop with modern technology as I have seen the analytics over the last 3 years. 29% in 2012-2013, 20% in 2013-14 and now 13.4% as you have stated. So I am anticipating the future..next year its inevitable that it will drop off again. Will provide fallback option for visitors to view the old website and a message to upgrade their browser. This is where the industry is going IE9+ with graceful degradation. Microsoft is also slashing support for IE8 (security and technical) from Jan 2016 which will mean that companies will most likely be updating their security policies to latest IE in not so distant future.

Answer (score 0):

49.34% of your users use Internet Explorer.
11,2% of them use IE8 and 15,95% use IE7.

So 0.4964*(11.2+15.68)=**13.4%** of your audience use IE8 and lower.
If you drop support of IE8 you'll make your site unavailable for 13% of your audience.

It's relatively high percent and it means that your audience is relatively conservative and don't use modern software.